# How to get the hash from the current route during startup using the router instance?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created a new Vue project using the router via `npm init vue@latest`. During startup I want to get the hash from the url, but I can't read it during startup.

For reproduction purposes I modified the **App.vue** file to

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
import { ref } from "vue";

const hashFromRoute = ref("");
const hashFromWindow = ref("");

const route = useRoute();
hashFromRoute.value = route.hash.substring(1);

hashFromWindow.value = window.location.hash.substring(1);
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div>Hash from route: {{ hashFromRoute }}</div>
    <div>Hash from window: {{ hashFromWindow }}</div>
  </div>
  <!-- ... render router view here ... -->
</template>
```

and run the app with a sample hash `http://localhost:3000/#foo=bar`

The hash from the route is empty, the hash from the window is set. I think this is because the call in the App.vue file is too early? Do I have to use `window` here or is there a way to "wait" until the Vue instance is ready to read it?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want get url from
`http://localhost:3000/#/?foo=bar`

in case, you import error module

`import { useRoute } from "vue-router"`

```
const route  = useRoute();
const {query} = route;
console.log(query.foo) // bar
```

Comment: @NNNzs using `useRoute` struggles with the same problems. It returns an empty string for `useRoute().hash`

Comment: ```http://localhost:3000/#/?foo=bar``` do you lose ```/``` after ```#```  and  the symbol ```?```

Comment: I personally think that adding `/?` after the `#` is not correct because I want to read the hash and not the query params

Comment: what mode do you use in vue-router? createWebHistory or createWebHashHistory ?
see 
[https://router.vuejs.org/api/#hash](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#hash)

Comment: currently I'm using `createWebHistory`. My example code works inside other Views, I think that's because the other view is the router view and has access to the "ready to use" instance